# Highly conductive lossless medium

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

I've came across the term "highly conductive lossless medium" in the context of electromagnetic waves travelling in materials.

I'm wondering how to make sense of that statement? I thought "highly conductive" implies there's energy through ohmic heating.  However how can that then be a "lossless medium"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good conductor is one for which $\frac{\sigma}{\omega\epsilon}\gg 1$ but a material is (nearly) lossless if the decay constant 
$$
\alpha=\sqrt{\frac{\omega^2\mu\epsilon}{2}}
\left[\sqrt{1+\frac{\sigma^2}{\omega^2\epsilon^2}}-1\right]^{1/2}
$$
is small.  Ultra-low frequency electromagnetic waves propagating in rock have $\sigma\sim 10^{-3}S/m$ and $\epsilon\sim 10\epsilon_0$, yielding
$$
\frac{\sigma}{\omega\epsilon}\sim 2\times 10^7
$$
and thus a good conductor while $\alpha\sim 2\times 10^{-5}$, so rock is nearly lossless at that frequency.

Note that geologists have measured such ultra low-frequency waves prior of some earthquakes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the authors of the text you quote had in mind, but, for example, superconductors are both "highly conductive" and "lossless".